# How to invoke a java method in ColdFusion 8 and pass a coldfusion Session variable to it?

Tags: java, methods, coldfusion, invoke

I am trying to invoke the java method below to a CFM page and I can not seem to get it. Additionally I need to set the values from CF session variables.

Provider.sendResponse(getServletContext(), response, IntegrationIDs.AuthnContextClasses.name, userName, attributes);

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Here is my code example

```
<cfset Obj = createobject("java","com.blah.blah.blah.Provider")/>

<cfset servletContext = />
<cfset response = />
<cfset serverName = SESSION.server/>
<cfset authnContext = />
<cfset uid = SESSION.uid />
<cfset attributes = />
<cfset targetUrl = http://yyy.com/>

<cfset Obj_value = Obj.sendResponse(
             javax.servlet.ServletContext servletContext,
             javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response,
             java.lang.String ServerName,
             java.lang.String authnContext,
             java.lang.String uid,
             java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>attributes,
             java.lang.String targetUrl)/>
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way. Thank you in advance for any assistance. Greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't show the actual invoking of the object. I should see something like createobject("java","com.blah.blah.blah.classname").init()  followed by "setup" of varialbes to pass ... like "Repsonse=session.somevariabl" ... the example you give is too incomplete to tell exactly where you are stumped.

To access a session variable you use "session.XXX". Session is like a hash table or vector (a "structure" in CF lingo). if "username" was stored in the session your example above *could* look like

Provider.sendResponse(getServletContext(), response, IntegrationIDs.AuthnContextClasses.name, *session.Username*, attributes);

But with out a bit more example code to go on I'm not sure what problem you need to solve :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define the parameter types in your call. You are confusing calling a method with defining one.

```
<cfset Obj_value = Obj.sendResponse(
         servletContext,
         response,
         ServerName,
         authnContext,
         uid,
         attributes,
         targetUrl)/>
```